# Get the result from SOLR searching

Tags: java, solr, xml-parsing

i'm new in using SOLR as a searcher. I'm using the standard SolrServlet as a searcher, e.g.

```
final SolrCore core = SolrCore.getSolrCore();
SolrServletRequest solrReq = new SolrServletRequest(core, request);
SolrQueryResponse solrRsp = new SolrQueryResponse();
try {

  SolrRequestHandler handler = core.getRequestHandler(solrReq.getQueryType());
  if (handler==null) {
    log.warning("Unknown Request Handler '" + solrReq.getQueryType() +"' :" + solrReq);
    throw new SolrException(SolrException.ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST,"Unknown Request Handler '" + solrReq.getQueryType() + "'", true);
  }
  core.execute(handler, solrReq, solrRsp );
  if (solrRsp.getException() == null) {
    QueryResponseWriter responseWriter = core.getQueryResponseWriter(solrReq);
    response.setContentType(responseWriter.getContentType(solrReq, solrRsp));
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
    fields.add("content");        
    solrRsp.setReturnFields(fields);
    responseWriter.write(out, solrReq, solrRsp);
```

I'm getting the correct answers, but what I'm asking is how can I get the content of the response before it is written from the writer? I know that the return is doc, and I have a field "content" in the doc that I want to get, but before the response page is generated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of using Solr in Java is through [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj). SolrServletRequest, SolrRequestHandler, etc, are "internal" classes of Solr, not meant to be generally used by consumers.

You can also [embed Solr in your application](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr), although it's not generally recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, put the things is, is there any way just to get the content of the field? Because i don't want to create a new app, just use solr itself, always with the same query. I actualy, get the source code of the SolrServlet, and re-map it the web.xml. I'm getting inside this servlet, but don't know how to get the value of the field.

Comment: try using velocity for that - its included as plugin already and should me more straightforward